# why elasticsearch won't run on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I'm trying to determine if the elasticsearch instance is running, but it doesn't appear to be:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo service elasticsearch status
 * elasticsearch is not running
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo service elasticsearch start
 * Starting Elasticsearch Server  [ OK ] 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo service elasticsearch status
 * elasticsearch is not running
and

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch status
 * elasticsearch is not running
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
 * Starting Elasticsearch Server  [ OK ] 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch status
 * elasticsearch is not running
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/elasticsearch# sudo service elasticsearch restart
 * Stopping Elasticsearch Server  [ OK ] 
 * Starting Elasticsearch Server  [ OK ] 
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/elasticsearch# sudo service elasticsearch status
 * elasticsearch is not running
```

and

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/_nodes/_all/process?pretty
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

and

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/elasticsearch$ sudo netstat -nlp
tcp6       0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN      4413/java
```

**UPD**

My elasticsearch.log:

```
[2014-12-03 00:00:02,161][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Zero] [logstash-2014.12.03] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], shards [5]/[1], mappings [_default_]
[2014-12-03 00:00:02,617][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Zero] [logstash-2014.12.03] update_mapping [logs] (dynamic)
[2014-12-03 00:00:12,737][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Zero] [logstash-2014.12.03] update_mapping [logs] (dynamic)
[2014-12-03 00:00:17,587][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Zero] [logstash-2014.12.03] update_mapping [logs] (dynamic)
[2014-12-03 00:00:18,842][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Zero] [logstash-2014.12.03] update_mapping [logs] (dynamic)
[2014-12-03 01:00:01,430][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Zero] [logstash-2014.11.25] deleting index
[2014-12-03 09:46:57,461][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Zero] [logstash-2014.12.03] update_mapping [logs] (dynamic)
```

Comment: check elasticsearch logs and update with error logs

Comment: Can you check what is running on 9200?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Elasticsearch service init script doesn't print any error information on console or log file when it fails to startup, instead it ridiculously shows `[OK]`.

You have to run elaticsearch manually with the same user and same parameters as what the init script does to check what's going wrong. The error message will be printed on console.

On my Ubuntu 14.10 with elasticsearch-1.4.1.deb installed, without any path changed, the command to run elastisearch is:

```
sudo -u elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -d -p /var/run/elasticsearch.pid --default.config=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml --default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch --default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch --default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch --default.path.work=/tmp/elasticsearch --default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch
```

I just added a line into `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch` to print out the above command:

```
# Start Daemon
log_daemon_msg "sudo -u $ES_USER $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS"    # <-- Add this line
start-stop-daemon --start -b --user "$ES_USER" -c "$ES_USER" --pidfile "$PID_FILE" --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
log_end_msg $?
```

Comment: Thanks!  I opened a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/elasticsearch/+bug/1465374) if anyone wants to "me too" it.

Comment: I'd just comment that on Vagrant I had this issue caused by running out of memory.

Comment: YMMV but I had to add the line just after the line that starts with  `DAEMON_OPTS=`.

Answer (score 26):

The elasticsearch user cannot write the PID file because it has no permissions to create a file in /var/run/:

```
FileNotFoundException[/var/run/elasticsearch.pid (Keine Berechtigung)]
```

The fix: create the directory /var/run/elasticsearch/, change its ownership to elasticsearch:elasticsearch, and change the PID file location to this directory in the init script.

```
mkdir -p /var/run/elasticsearch
chown elasticsearch: /var/run/elasticsearch
sed -e 's|^PID_FILE=.*$|PID_FILE=/var/run/$NAME/$NAME.pid|g' -i /etc/init.d/elasticsearch
```

Once you get that far, here's the next error you might see:

```
ElasticsearchIllegalStateException[Failed to obtain node lock, is the following location writable?: [/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch]]
```

Again a resource does not have the correct permissions for the elasticsearch user.

```
chown -R elasticsearch: /var/lib/elasticsearch
```

Not done yet. Now you have to edit /etc/init.d/elasticsearch and remove this line:

```
test "$START_DAEMON" == true || exit 0
```

This line is utter garbage and is guaranteed to cause an exit.

Now it should finally start.

Comment: FYI, you alternatively can un-comment the START_DAEMON line in /etc/defaults/elasticsearch instead of tweaking the init.d script.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful this one. I wonder why that's not properly configured in Ubuntu itself, though.

Comment: Worked for me with just the first step (still one step too many).

Answer (score 11):

> If you are using Elasticsearch > 5.0

Min/max heap size requirements for Elasticsearch 5.0 are now both defaulted to 2gb

Check the `ls /tmp/hs_err_pid*.log` files, in the logs you'll see that JVM failed to start ES because of insufficient memory.

You can adjust the heap size settings in `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`. Adjust the lines `-Xms2g` and `-Xmx2g` to `-Xms1g` and `-Xmx1g` respectively, if you're on a box with 2 GB of RAM. If you're going to use a box with 1 GB of RAM I would recommend using `-Xms512m` and `-Xmx512m.`

[Reference](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21300)

Comment: Man, you are my hero! I've been looking hours for this!

Comment: Thanks mate. I'm glad that my answer was able to save your time.

Comment: Do you maybe know how to fix this issue with Docker and Plesk? Docker is running my ElasticSearch currently and i have no clue how to fix it with docker. Finding this solution was hard, applying it with docker is even harder :P

Comment: I don't use docker, but i believe you can change the `jvm.options` via your docker configuration settings. If thats not possible, try to create your own `jvm.options` and replace that in your provisioning server.

Comment: same issue when i changed to Xms512m and -Xmx512m same error any alternative approach !

Comment: This is the newer default heap requirements. Check your `ls /tmp/hs_err_pid*.log` and see if it's causing any memory issue.

Answer (score 8):

While the accepted answer command worked for me using Elasticsearch 1.7.3, with some changes in Elasticsearch >2.0 running the accepted answer command would produce

```
es.default.config is no longer supported. elasticsearch.yml 
must be placed in the config directory and cannot be renamed
```

[Github Issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14347#issuecomment-152946882)

The command as specified in the above Github issue would now be:

```
sudo -u elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -d -p /var/run/elasticsearch.pid --path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch --default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch --default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch --default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch --default.path.work=/tmp/elasticsearch --default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue this morning.  After much digging, we found out  it was caused by an unsuccessful Java 8 installation.  All was fine after Java 8 installation had been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The command line parameters that [@aleung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94148/aleung) refers to can be set in the configuration file. By default, the parameters are commented out.

Set the following in `/etc/default/elasticsearch`

```
################################
# Elasticsearch
################################

# Elasticsearch home directory
ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch configuration directory
CONF_DIR=/etc/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch data directory
DATA_DIR=/var/lib/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch logs directory
LOG_DIR=/var/log/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch PID directory
PID_DIR=/var/run/elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 1):

This command resolved my issue:

```
sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch/
```

[Referenced from @imsaar github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10671)

Comment: this worked for me on a Ubuntu droplet on digitalocean. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me, this problem was caused by the Elasticsearch Data and/or Logs directory being at 100% disk usage. Run `df -h` to see whether the directory your Elasticsearch process is using for data and logs has free space or not.

Answer (score 0):

I got to the same point after I've done apt-get dist-upgrade - JAVA got updated to "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)" version.

My ES did not want to start. I found the cause here (tail -n100 /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin [license] is incompatible with Elasticsearch [2.3.2]. Was designed for version [2.3.1]
```

I just removed the plugin (bin/plugin remove license) and started ES successfully.

I hope this will help others.