# Can't start elasticsearch on Ubuntu 10.4 - es.default.config is no longer supported

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I've never used ES, nor configured it, but that's a dependency in my project that I must install. I've no idea how to setup it, there isn't any kind of documentation.

I have used several tutorials and different ways to install ES 2.1.1, and I've been blocked by this command: `sudo service elasticsearch restart` which does... nothing. Nothing gets started, no log whatsoever in the console.

```
➜  ~  sudo service elasticsearch restart
Stopping Elasticsearch...
Elasticsearch was not running.
Starting Elasticsearch...
Waiting for Elasticsearch................................
WARNING: Elasticsearch may have failed to start.
```

Indeed, there is nothing running on `localhost:9200`.

I recently changed the rights allocated to `/etc/elasticsearch` and its subfolders:

```
➜  /etc  ll | grep elas
drwxr-x---  3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Jan  9 01:02 elasticsearch
```

Before it was `drwxr-x---  3 root elasticsearch ...`, I don't really know if that change is good or bad (I read on internet that for Ubuntu there was a bug that seems to have been resolved since about ownership, so at some point I just had to try, no changes whatsoever)

I tried to install it using different ways:

1. Using the Ubuntu Software Center with the `.deb` file from the official website https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch which just told me the `.deb` was badly formatted and could damage the OS. So I didn't install it.
2. I tried that script: https://gist.github.com/janpieper/2c96fb12d9b566a679a5 using the command `bin/elasticsearch.sh 1.7` (yeah, I don't even know the version I'm supposed to install, so I just tried several of them) but it failed.
3. I tried https://gist.github.com/ricardo-rossi/8265589463915837429d which is the script that inspired the previous one, but this one was kept up-to-date and didn't fail. It installed all dependencies correctly, but at the very end it couldn't startup ES.
4. I tried the same with the 2.1 and then 2.1.1 versions, same.
   5.I started wondering why I got no logs whatsoever and found some interesting links like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/elasticsearch/+bug/1465374 saying that logs where broken [why elasticsearch won't run on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273998/why-elasticsearch-wont-run-on-ubuntu-14-04) and http://sandlininc.com/?p=747 but none of them were really useful to me. I realized by reading the SO post that I didn't have any `elasticsearch` user, so I thought the install had not been done well.
5. I uninstalled ES `sudo apt-get remove elasticsearch -f` and decided to install it again, using the `.deb` that failed the first time, but from command line, this time. `sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-2.1.1.deb`. Install went well, but couldn't start the instance either.
6. I decided to change the rights of the `/etc/elasticsearch/` subfolders, hoping it would fix it. Nah. Same thing.
7. I decided to ask for help, because I had no more idea how to find a solution for this.
8. While writing, I remembered the fact that I didn't have an `elasticsearch` user on step 5. Now I do, so I read more about the guy's solution. I changed the logging config to log `TRACE` rather than `INFO` in `/etc/elasticsearch/logging.yml`, just in case.

I just ran his command and I got:

```
➜  ~  sudo -u elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -d -p /var/run/elasticsearch.pid --default.config=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml --default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch --default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch --default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch --default.path.work=/tmp/elasticsearch --default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch
[sudo] password for vadorequest: 
➜  ~  [2016-01-09 01:42:01,230][INFO ][bootstrap] es.default.config is no longer supported. elasticsearch.yml must be placed in the config directory and cannot be renamed.
```

But that's an `info`, so it shouldn't lead to a silent crash. Anyway I don't understand what I should do with that. What is the `config` directory?

---

I finally was able to do it by downloading the `1.7.4` `.deb` version and install it using `sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-1.7.4.deb` and then running `sudo -u elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -d --default.config=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml --default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch --default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch --default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch --default.path.work=/tmp/elasticsearch --default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch`
.

I had to remove the -p option for the pid because the file didn't exist. I got no log whatsoever but hiting my `localhost:9200` gives me the expected

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Hideko Takata",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.4",
    "build_hash" : "0d3159b9fc8bc8e367c5c40c09c2a57c0032b32e",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-12-15T11:25:18Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try check elasticsearch.log at `/var/log/elasticsearch`. Please share it here and it should give you some clue

Here is my ES setup steps on ubuntu. Hope it can help you

```
apt-get update
apt-get install openjdk-7-jre

wget https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.7.2.deb
dpkg -i elasticsearch-1.7.2.deb

init 6
```

[ES setup configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html)

```
vi /etc/fstab 
disable swap ->

vi /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
edit -> bootstrap.mlockall: true
edit -> cluster.name: "SET YOUR CLUSTER NAME"
edit -> node.name: NODE NAME # can leave it blank

vim /etc/security/limits.conf
add -> elasticsearch soft memlock unlimited
add -> elasticsearch hard memlock unlimited
add -> elasticsearch soft nofile 65535
add -> elasticsearch hard nofile 65535

vi /etc/init.d/elasticsearch
edit -> ES_HEAP_SIZE=1000m               ## 50% of instance memory

update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10
service elasticsearch start
```

Comment: I only get the same message: `[2016-01-09 01:42:01,230][INFO ][bootstrap                ] es.default.config is no longer supported. elasticsearch.yml must be placed in the config directory and cannot be renamed.` which doesn't help me much.

Comment: this might be your solution? https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14763

Comment: Nop, I found that thread also, but I didn't have his kinda duplicated config file `elasticsearch.service.dpkg-dist`, so it didn't help. :/

Comment: added my ES setup steps. hope it can help you

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution. At least a workaround for now.